# ping 8.8.8.8 from mininet host works first time after restart

Tags: virtualbox, ping, mininet

I have a weird problem. 
I have mininet installed on a virtualbox VM. on restart if I try 'h1 ping -c 1 8.8.8.8' it works. I stop mininet and do a mn -c and try the same ping again, I get 100% packet loss until I restart the VM. Could not figure out the solution to this.

Below is my code taken from : https://techandtrains.com/2013/11/24/mininet-host-talking-to-internet/

def myNetwork():

```
net = Mininet( topo=None, build=False)

info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
net.addController(name='c0')

info( '*** Add switches\n')
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')
Intf( 'eth1', node=s1 ) #Some Problem

info( '*** Add hosts\n')
h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip='0.0.0.0')
h2 = net.addHost('h2', ip='0.0.0.0')

info( '*** Add links\n')
net.addLink(h1, s1)
net.addLink(h2, s1)

info( '*** Starting network\n')
net.start()
#os.popen('ovs-vsctl add-port s1 eth0')
h1.cmdPrint('dhclient '+h1.defaultIntf().name)
h2.cmdPrint('dhclient '+h2.defaultIntf().name)
CLI(net)
net.stop()
```